# Jboss JVM arguments configuration for hotswap-agent and DCEVM

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-7, hotswap, hotswapagent

For some background, I am trying to run Jboss EAP 7.1 along with Eclipse and both are connected via Jboss Tools.

Okay so my main problem is how to configure JVM arguments to the Jboss Server JVM since I intend to use the DCEVM inorder to use HotDeployment.

The Argument I want to add is :

> java -XXaltjvm=dcevm -javaagent:c:\java\hotswap-agent.jar YourApp

I added it to the System Configuration inside the Mangement Console as per some web guides but Jboss doesn't seem to detect it. Also tried the JAVA_OPTS enviorment variable but it isn't affected.

Note : I am running Jboss on a Standalone configuration myself and I think Ecclipse's JBoss Tools does the same. As it uses the Standalone directory and configuration xml.

Comment: Did my answer help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Double click the JBoss server in the Servers View, this opens the Overview configuration page of that server as such.**
[image: JBoss Configuration Overview] 

**2. Click Open Launch Configuration (close to top left)**
[image: Edit Configuration]

**3. Then add the two parameters (selected in blue) as I did under "VM arguments" - be usre to include a space after the last argument that already exists prior to you editing.**

**4. Click the Apply button.**

**5. Restart the server instance**

**6. In the server output console window, on startup and close to very top you should now see JBoss shows it was started with those arguments.**

Comment: Glad it worked for you AbuBakar and I was able to help out!  Happy coding!